# Using WFS layers in LeafletJS

Tags: leaflet, wms

I have a simple git project here (link removed) that shows how I'm trying to load web feature service (WFS) layers into leaflet. Demo here (link removed)

My problem comes when I zoom in to the most zoomed layer. There should be two layers present (wells as blue markers, and land parcels as white polygons). Sometimes the parcels work and other times they don't show up. By toggling the zoom up and down to the maximum zoom, you'll be able to reproduce the results.

Can anybody see a better approach that will allow both the wells and parcels to load? My intention is to load more WFS layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your jsonp callback - you are using same function name for all layers and as result, there's some kind of overwriting of data going on.

To fix it, use different callback names:

```
// For citiesDefaultParameters
format_options : 'callback: getJson_cities',

// For wellsDefaultParameters, use
format_options : 'callback: getJson_wells',

// For parcelsDefaultParameters
format_options : 'callback: getJson_parcels',

// In load_wfs function, use:
$.ajax({
    ...
    jsonpCallback: 'getJson_' + name,
```

Comment: Zing! Works like a charm. Thank you.