# How can I zoomed to the cql_filter feature?

Tags: leaflet, geoserver, wms

I am using geoserver. I write the following code;

```
const mywms = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/taj/wms", {
    layers: 'taj:country',
    format: 'image/png',
    CQL_FILTER: 'name=pana'
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.4,
    version: '1.1.0',
    attribution: "country layer"
});
```

All is good. The layer get filtered. But I need the selected feature to zoom full extend.
I tried to center the mywms layer using this code; `map.fitBounds(mywms.GetBounds());`. But it shows the error; `mywms.getBOunds is not a function`. Any help?

Comment: Tile layers don't have bounds. Even though you've filtered the WMS data, the layer still covers the world.

Comment: Then how can I zoomed to the selected feature? Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is pointed out in the comments WMS requests contain the bounding box of the map in the request and so will always cover the whole of the map area.

To get the extent of a single feature you need to make a [WFS request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884385/using-wfs-layers-in-leafletjs) with the filter included and then zoom to the extent of that feature when it is returned.

Comment: you mean WFS request with `cql_filter` directly return the bound box that that selected filter area?

Comment: no, it will return a feature with a geometry that you can zoom to

Comment: Actually I have more than 100 districts in my dataset. I want to add them using cql_filter. I am trying to zoom the selected feature at full extend. Is it possible?

Comment: yes, take the geometry of the returned (filtered) feature and zoom to it's extent

Comment: Thanks for  your suggestion. really appreciate. I make a  [WFS request](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/89884/138203) according to this guide. I can't able to `enable_jsonp` in my server (I have to enable_jsonp first than I can request WFS). [I also asked for help in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58618351/how-can-i-stop-the-geoserver). Please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: you could use simple gml instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201583/discussion-between-tekson-and-ian-turton).

Comment: Yes It is the best answer. Finally I solve the whole puzzle. I also put my code in this question and explain my experience so no one will stuck with this problem again. Thank you very much for helping me brother. Really appreciated. I updated the code with your suggestion. finally it work. It is such a wonderful day for me.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much for all of the helping hands. And special thanks to Mr. [Ina Turton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/439194/ian-turton) who helps me to find out the actual problem and get the solution. my url for the wfs server looks like this;

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/tajikistan/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=taj%3Acountry&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson
```

I write the following code to for zooming into my cql_filter area:

```
//Geoserver Web Feature Service
$.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs',{
  type: 'GET',
  data: {
      service: 'WFS',
      version: '1.1.0',
      request: 'GetFeature',
      typename: 'tajikistan:country',
      CQL_FILTER: "name_rg='Centre'",
      srsname: 'EPSG:4326',
      outputFormat: 'text/javascript',
      },
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonpCallback:'callback:handleJson',
  jsonp:'format_options'
  });


function handleJson(data) {
    var requiredArea = L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(requiredArea.getBounds())
}
```

In this code the `CQL_FILTER` is used for to filter out the required area. In my case the data having column name `name_rg` which have the property as `Centre`. I query this region using this code. I fetch the data using ajax method. I write the code little tricky because the regular ajax call doesn't callback the handleJson function and return an `parseJson error`. And finally I added the variable named as `requiredArea`. Get bounds of this region and set bounds of the required region and added into the map.