# How can I stop the geoserver?

Tags: jsonp, shutdown, geoserver

Actually I want to `enable_jsonp` in my geoserver. For this I have to change the code as suggested by [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/57608/138203). When I tried to stop the geoserver (located inside `geoserver2..15.0/bin/shutdown.bat` folder), the cmd was crashed. I am not able to enable the jsonp unless the geoserver was stoped. I know, I install the geoserver `install as service` in installation process. I think this issue may be arises from there. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stop the service.

Launch Windows Services (type `services` in the taskbar or run `cmd` then call `services.msc`), find Geoserver, do a right click and choose `stop`.

Note that you can then restart it from there (right click, `start`)